# Visual Studio 2012 SQL Report Project - Use shared data source on report server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I feel like I am missing something.  I am trying to reference a Shared Data Source that currently exists on my companies' MS SSRS Report Server.  I have created a new Business Intelligence - Reporting Services project in Visual Studio 2012 and I know how to create a new Data Source but I cannot figure out how to reference the shared data source on the server.
Maybe it is not even possible, but I thought that was the point of the shared data sources.  Thank you in advance for your input on this.

B Schroed

Answer (score 1):

A shared data source is shared between reports on the same Report Server where the data source is.

In your case, you can create a new shared data source on your SSRS Report Server, which links to the same Database(or whatever data source type you're using) as the Shared Data Source that currently exists on your companies' MS SSRS Report Server, and use that new shared data source across the reports deployed on your report server.